# How to write dynamic sql in Oracle Stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

Basically in my update sql query column names going to be dynamic like

```
update bi_employee set <this_is_dynamic_column> where emp_id = 12
```

Below is the stored procedure that I have written so far.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Sp_run_employee_updates
IS
  CURSOR c_emp IS
    SELECT *
    FROM   BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE
    WHERE  EFFECTIVE_DATE = To_date('30-Apr-2012', 'dd-mm-yy');
BEGIN
    FOR employee_update IN c_emp LOOP
        declare update_sql varchar2(225);
        update_sql := 'UPDATE BI_EMPLOYEE   SET     '
                      || employee_update.column_name
                      || '= employee_update.new_value  WHERE     emp_id = '
                      || employee_update.employee_id;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Its giving me foloowing errors

> Error(17,13): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     constant exception      table long double ref    char time timestamp interval date binary national character    nchar The symbol "" was substituted for "=" to continue.

---

> Error(22,5): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior The symbol "begin" was substituted for "UPDATE" to continue.

---

> Error(31,6): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a- This should be like this:

```
to_date('30-Apr-2012','dd-mon-yyyy');
```

b- You can do it like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE SP_RUN_EMPLOYEE_UPDATES IS  

  update_sql varchar2(225);

  CURSOR c_emp IS
   SELECT * 
   FROM BI_EMPLOYEE_UPDATE 
   WHERE EFFECTIVE_DATE = to_date('30-Apr-2012','dd-mon-yyyy');

BEGIN

 FOR employee_update in c_emp LOOP

     update_sql :=  'UPDATE BI_EMPLOYEE SET ' || employee_update.column_name || 
                    '= :1 WHERE emp_id = :2' ;

  execute immediate update_sql using employee_update.new_value, employee_update.employee_id;

 END LOOP;

END SP_RUN_EMPLOYEE_UPDATES;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The proc is getting compiled now. But unfortunately it does not run. New values can be strings or numbers. BI_EMPLOYEE table has columns with datatype varchar2 and number. Both of them can have new values in emp_update table , but the datatype of new_value in emp_update is varchar2. So, with this query it gives me error like if new vlaue is 'John', 'john' is invalid identifier. Please help.

Comment: You need to use bind variables for employee_update.new_value and employee_update.employee_id.

Comment: Also, as the column names are known before hand there's no need to use dynamic SQL. This could also be done in a single statement with `merge` or more efficiently with `bulk collect`

Comment: @Ben. I can see how to do it in one **dynamic** statement (in the loop, concatenate the `<col>=<value>` parts and then there's only one execute immediate), but how can you do it with a `merge` or `bulk` ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade, because it appears as though, the OP isn't doing anything dynamically at all. The `employee_update.column_name`, is known by definition as it's in a cursor, as is the `emp_id`. The OP could of course have not taken this into account but as the question stands I see no reason to use dynamic SQL at all.

Comment: @Ben, using `merge` or `bulk` sounds a better solution than mine, can you add it as an answer ?

Comment: @A.B.Cade Hi I am still getting error while trying to run the proc. The error is missing equal sign in "execute immediate update_sql using employee_update.new_value, employee_update.employee_id; ". Please help.

Comment: add `dbms_output.put_line(update_sql);` before the execute immediate. Maybe the update string isn't built right for some cases

Comment: Does employee_update.column_name has a value which is a column in BI_EMPLOYEE ???

Comment: Yes @psaraj12, that's how I understood OP

Comment: Thanks @A.B.Cade ,OP can you  please post the contents of employee_update.column_name since the missing equal sign error may be because of this value